# How to Redirect Form Submissions to Another View

Tags: python, django, forms, url

I have the following django form, which will be used by users to input a query and select a model to search that particular query:

```
from django import forms
class search_forms(forms.Form):

    search_query = forms.CharField(label='search_query')
    path_choices =  [('urlpath1/','model name 1'),
    ('urlpath2/','model name 2')...]
    model_paths = forms.ChoiceField(label='model_paths',choices=path_choices)
```

This form is used to populate a template which consists of a input field of text for for users to submit queries, and a drop down field which identifies which model the query should be directed to (the path_choices variable in forms.py).

Thew views.py is as follows, which needs to change to the following somehow:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = search_forms(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'template_for_model_paths.html', {'form': form, 's_results': s_results})
    else:
        form = search_forms()
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form,})
```

Currently, the form template yields a GET result as follows: /search?search_query=QUERY&model_paths=model_path%2F

What I would like to accomplish is: model_path/Query as the result, which I can feed back to the view for the search form and use it to redirect the view relevant for model_path.

How should I accomplish this? Does this approach make sense? Or am I misapplying the intent of the form functionality?

Comment: Changing the Url with Dynamic parameter would help out!

Comment: Are you able to post the relevant template code?